# DynamoDB update list of list items

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I need your help to update/add item in a list of list of DynamoDB.

I want to add and update a list that is composed by a list. 
How can i do that? Thanks for your help

**Here my example:**

***DATABASE***

```
Item{1}
       idProject:"15azeze-55ze"
       dateCreationProjectString:   08/01/2018 14:6:32  
       environnements:    List[1]   
          0 MAP {3}
              idEnvironnement: "11-aa",
              name:"Exemple Environnement"
              tasks[0]
```

***NodeJS code :***

```
let newTask =  {
   authorTask :      "Toto",
   dateCreationTask: "01/01/1960",
   idTask:           "154-141-aa41",
   nameTask:         "Task name ..."
};



dynamodbdc.update({
    TableName: "projects",
    Key: { idProject: "15azeze-55ze", idEnvironnement:"11-aa" },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
    UpdateExpression: 'set #environnements.#tasks = list_append(if_not_exists(#environnements.#tasks, :empty_list), :newTask)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#environnements' : 'environnements',
      '#tasks'          : 'tasks',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':newTask': [newTask],
      ':empty_list': []
    }
  }, function(error, stdout) {
          if(error){
            console.log("error==", error)                
          else {            
             console.log("Nice thank you !!")
          } 
  });
```

Comment: What does your example code do?

Comment: add a new task in an environnement done

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep the `tasks` attribute as SET ('SS') which will simplify to **NOT** add the duplicate values. Otherwise, it would be difficult to fulfil the scenario.

Also, you may the index of the `environments` attribute list to form the update expression correctly. There is no options in the dynamodb api to workout the index automatically.

The below code should work if you define the `tasks` attribute as SET.

**Insert item code:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName : table,
    Item : {
        "idProject" : "15azeze-55ze",
        "dateCreationProjectString" : Date(),
        "environnements" : [{
      "idEnvironnement" : "11-aa",
      "name" : "Example Environments",
      "tasks" : docClient.createSet(["1"])
    }]
    }
};

console.log("Adding a new item...");
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

**Sample update item working code:-**

The `ADD` operation will ensure that it doesn't add duplicates to the SET

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    TableName: "projects",
    Key: {
        "idProject" : "15azeze-55ze"
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'ADD environnements['+0+'].tasks :tasksVal',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":tasksVal": docClient.createSet(["2"])
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
};

console.log("Updating the item...");
docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that is a good response but how do you indice/index of the item in the list ? Is it possible with a query? do you have an example?

Comment: Do you mean creating GSI on the attribute in the list? If yes, it is not possible to create index on complex object (like list, map etc). You can create index on scalar attributes only (like String, Number etc).